# OpenGL: using instanced drawing to draw with the framebuffer I'm drawing into

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to basically "add" framebuffers, or better the colortexture attachmement of framebuffers. I found a way to do this is by having a shader which gets all the textures and renders their combination.
But to improve the performance wouldn't it be better to just have one shader and framebuffer, and then through instanced drawing the shader draws onto the framebuffer colortexture attachement it is using for drawing?

A bit better explained:

I have 2 framebuffers: Default and Framebuffer1.

I bind Framebuffer1
and give the colortexture attachment of Framebuffer1 as uniform "Fb1_cta" to the following fragment shader:

```
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec2 TexCoords;


uniform sampler2D Fb1_cta;

void main()
{
    vec3 text = texture(Framebuffer1, TexCoords).rgb;

    FragColor = vec4(vec3(0.5) + text, 1.0);
}
```

So i draw into Framebuffer1, but also use the current colortexture attachement for the drawing.

Now I call `glDrawArraysInstanced` with instancecount 2.
The first renderpass should draw the whole texture in grey (rgb = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5)) and the second should add another vec3(0.5) to that, so the result will be white. That however didn't really work so I split the `glDrawArraysInstanced` into 2 `glDrawArrays` and checked the 2 results.

Now while the first pass works as intended:[Result of first rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0dOI.jpg)

The second didn't (btw this is the same result as with the `glDrawArraysInstanced`):[Result of second rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfHLg.jpg)

To me this pretty much looks like the two renderpasses aren't done sequentially, but in parallel. So I did rerun my code but this time with a bit of time passing between the calls and that seemed to have solved the issue.

Now I wonder is there any way to tell OpenGL that those calls should truly be sequential and might there even be a way to do it with `glDrawArraysInstanced` to improve the performance?
Is there in general a more elegant solution to this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you cannot read from a texture image that is also being rendered to. To achieve the level of performance necessary for real-time rendering, it is essential to take advantage of parallelism wherever possible. Fragment shader invocations are generally not processed sequentially. On a modern GPU, there will be thousands and thousands of fragment shader invocations running concurrently during rendering. Even fragment shader invocations from separate draw calls. OpenGL and GLSL are designed specifically to enable this sort of parallelization.

From the OpenGL 4.6 specification, section 9.3.1:

> Specifically, the values of rendered fragments are undefined if any shader stage
>   fetches texels and the same texels are written via fragment shader outputs, even
>   if the reads and writes are not in the same draw call, unless any of the following
>   exceptions apply:
>
> - The reads and writes are from/to disjoint sets of texels (after accounting for
>     texture filtering rules).
> - There is only a single read and write of each texel, and the read is in
>     the fragment shader invocation that writes the same texel (e.g. using
>     texelFetch2D(sampler, ivec2(gl_FragCoord.xy), 0);).
> - If a texel has been written, then in order to safely read the result a texel fetch
>     must be in a subsequent draw call separated by the command
>
>   `void TextureBarrier( void );`
>
>   `TextureBarrier` will guarantee that writes have completed and caches have
>     been invalidated before subsequent draw calls are executed.

The OpenGL implementation is allowed to (and, as you have noticed, will actually) run multiple drawcalls concurrently if possible. Across all the fragment shader invocations that your two drawcalls produce, you do have some that read and write from/to the same sets of texels. There is more than a single read and write of each texel from different fragment shader invocations. The drawcalls are not separated by a call to `glTextureBarrier()`. Thus, your code produces undefined results.

A drawcall alone does not constitute a rendering pass. A rendering pass is usually understood as the whole set of operations that produce a certain piece of output (like a particular image in a framebuffer) that is then usually again consumed as an input into another pass. To make your two draw calls "truly sequential", you could call `glTextureBarrier()` between issuing the draw calls.

But if all you want to do is draw two triangles, one after the other, on top of each other into the same framebuffer, all you have to do is draw two triangles and use additive blending. You don't need instancing. You don't need separate drawcalls. Just draw two triangles. OpenGL requires blending to take place in the order in which the triangles from which the fragments originated were specified. Be aware that if you happen to have depth testing enabled, chances are your depth test is going to prevent the second triangle from ever being drawn unless you did change the depth testing function to something other than the default.

The downside of blending is that you're limited to a set of a few fixed functions that you can select as your blend function. But add is one of them. If you need more complex blending functions, there are vendor-specific extensions that enable what is typically called "programmable blending" on some GPUs…

Note that all of the above only concerns drawcalls that read-from and write to the same target. Drawcalls that read from a target that ealier drawcalls rendered to are guaranteed to be sequenced after the drawcalls that produced their input.